# How to find a sent item I have moved

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have tried to move a sent mail from my "sent" folder to another folder. Now it has gone from both folders and it is not in the deleted folder either. Where can I find the mail now?

Comment: Are you using any of the search functions, or just eye-balling it? If you are just eye-balling it and are specifically looking at the "To", it will have changed to your name, instead of the person you sent it to. Emails outside of the "Sent" folder show who they are "From", even emails you've sent but moved out of the "Sent" folder. In this case, the "From" is you.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the search functions under the Extra menu, e.g. Direct Search. This opens a search edit box, then in the drop down to its right choose "all email items".